# Equivalence between Stepwise Regression and Lasso

Tags: lasso, stepwise-regression

A while ago I had learned of a theoretical result that suggested there was a correspondence with Forward/Backward/Stepwise regression and LASSO/RIDGE regression in terms of the coefficient of regularization and the p-value used to eliminate the variable.

Can anyone confirm/deny this and point me to a reference?

Comment: This definitely isn't so because lasso performs variable selection and regularization while stepwise regression only performs variable selection. It's possible there's a correspondence between the stepwise regressions and best subset regression, which penalizes the L0 norm of the regression coefficients, so no regularization takes place.

Comment: I have seen it before I am certain of it.  There is a correspondence between the p-value and the alpha chosen and its a formula.